# Custom rails routes not routing like I expect

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have a jquery that everyone at my site can click on to update their subscription that looks like this

```
<div id="role-options-<%= current_user.id %>" class="modal modalSubscription" style="display: none;">
  <%= simple_form_for current_user, :url => user_path(current_user), :html => {:method => :put, :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>

...Form stuff

  <div class="modal-footer">
    <%= f.submit "Update Settings", :class => "btn btn-green" %>
    <a class="btn btn-green closeModal" data-dismiss="modal" href="#">Close</a>
  </div>
 <% end %>
</div>
```

And i am trying to push this to a custom route that is an update subscription path.  I am using devise.  In a perfect world, i would like to send it to a separate controller that is labeled SubscriptionsController so that it can handle the update action.  I've tried many things in the routes

```
#I expected this to send the request to the subscription controller after i changed the :url to update_subscriptions_path, but it did not
 put "/users/update_subscription", :to => 'subscription#update'
```

I also tried just adding an "update_subscription" method in the controller and set the url in the form to 
    users_update_subscription_path

However this posted to the update path

Answer (score 0):

Alright so was making a mistake, the paths i was adding were after resources :users, it looks like rails sees the put request and automatically assumes that I want to update the user and didn't make it down to the extra route I had added.